# How to change json key name with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Need some help please.

I have a similar json file:

```
{
   "timestamp": "2022-09-20T08:16:00.000Z",
   "metadata": {   
   "orgID": "6780",
   "projectId": 0988,
  }
 },
 {
  "data":  
   "workers": [      
    {
     "identifiers": { 
      "FullName": null,
      "NINumber": null,
      "CompID": null
     },
     "lastName": null,
     "costCenter": null
    },
    {
     "codes": [  
       {
       "source": {
        "name": "net_salary",
        "value": 11500
       },
       "name": "net_salary",
       "code": "rt_sa",
       "value": 11500
      },
 {
     "identifiers": {
      "FullName": null,
      "NINumber": null,
      Comp ID": null
     },
     "lastName": null,
     "costCenter": null
    },
    {
     "codes": [
      {
       "source": {
        "name": "hiredate",
        "value": 3.333
       },
       "name": "hiredate",
       "code": "h_code",
       "value": 3.333
      },
```

I want to change the key names under source from name->fieldname and value to fieldvalue.
However, I don't want to change the keys where there are the keys: name, code, value.

I tried this but it is not correct:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test\PJSON.json') as f:
    payrolldata = json.load(f)
    source = payrolldata[1]['data']['workers'][1]['codes'][1]['source']
    print(source)
    oldvalue = source.keys()
    print(str(oldvalue).replace('name', 'newname').replace('value', 'value2'))
 payrolldata = str(oldvalue).replace('name', 'newname').replace('value', 'newvalue2')
 for d in payrolldata:
     d['newName':] = d.pop["'name':"]


with open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test\PJSON.json', "w") as f:
  json.dump(payrolldata, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Add a valid JSON data or python dictionary

Comment: Why don't you provide an example of the dict that is sintatically correct?

Comment: You won't be able to do a `str.replace()` since you have converted from the string form of `json` to the `dict` you have called `payrolldata`. You will need to recursively search for the keys and update the nested dicts.

Comment: I don't see `"\"name\":"` in your JSON keys. I'm guessing you are confused about what you are looking at.

Comment: @tripleee: There is: `"name": "net_salary"` for instance.

Comment: Give a valid input json and the json you are expecting as examples.

Comment: That's just `"name"`, not `"\"name\":"`

Comment: Your JSON doesn't look valid.  `Comp ID` is missing a quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't convert your dict into string and use something like this on you dict read from json file (with `json.load`)

```
def deep_replace_key(
    d,
    old_key: str,
    new_key: str,
    branch_name: str = None,
    replace: bool = False,
):
  """deep replace key in dict.

    Only make replacement if the we are in the branch branch_name."""
  if branch_name is None:
    replace = True
  if isinstance(d, dict):
    d_copy = d.copy()
    for key, value in d_copy.items():
      if key == old_key and replace:
        d[new_key] = d.pop(old_key)
      else:
        if branch_name and key == branch_name:
          deep_replace_key(value, old_key, new_key, branch_name, True)
        else:
          deep_replace_key(value, old_key, new_key, branch_name, False)
  elif isinstance(d, list):
    for item in d:
      deep_replace_key(item, old_key, new_key, branch_name, replace)
  return d
```

Here is a working test for this code

```
import unittest
# test
class TestDeepReplaceKey(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_deep_replace_key(self):
    d = {
        "codes": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "hiredate",
                    "value": 3.333
                },
                "not_source": {
                    "name": "hiredate",
                    "value": 3.333
                },
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "hiredate",
                    "value": 3.333
                },
                "not_source": {
                    "name": "hiredate",
                    "value": 3.333
                },
            },
        ]
    }

    d = deep_replace_key(d, "name", "new_name", "source", )
    self.assertEqual(d["codes"][0]["source"]["new_name"], "hiredate")
    self.assertEqual(d["codes"][0]["not_source"]["name"], "hiredate")

    d = deep_replace_key(d, "name", "new_name", )
    self.assertEqual(d["codes"][0]["not_source"]["new_name"], "hiredate")
```

So you can see if I call `deep_replace_key(d, "name", "new_name", "source", )` the change only happens in the source block.

If I omit mentioning "source" like this `deep_replace_key(d, "name", "new_name", )` change happens everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, it is changing also the key names where I don't want it to. I want it to change only the source block and not the key names underneath. Tried to get it to work but wasn't able to.

Comment: ok, let me change my code to fit your need

Comment: I changed the function. Hope it helps. If it does please accept the answer